# Combine JQuery functions for HTML2Canvas saving to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

The code below works, but how can I eliminate the step of having to select Preview first before the Download PDF is generated and works?

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
  // Global variables
  var captureArea = jQuery("#pdf"), 
      capturedData;

    jQuery("#btn-preview-image").on('click', function () {
      // To capture entire page
      jQuery('body').scrollTop(0);
      // Get canvas
      html2canvas(captureArea, {
         allowTaint: true,
         useCORS: true,
         taintTest: false,
         onrendered: function (canvas) {    
           jQuery("#previewImage").html("").append(canvas);
              capturedData = canvas;
           }
       });
    });

    jQuery("#btn-download").on('click', function () {
      var imgageData = capturedData.toDataURL("image/png");
      // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
      var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
      jQuery("#btn-download").attr("download", "screenshot.png").attr("href", newData);
  });
}); 
</script>
```